# appcode cannot find class installed by cocoapods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, appcode

When I use `appcode` the app can run normally. But `appcode` reports syntax error like below attached screenshot. This class is installed by `cocoapods`. What can I do to dismiss these `erros`?

[image]

Comment: make sure can you import IQKeyboardManager in AppDelegate ?

Comment: make sure you are opening the workspace file and not just the project file and then import the library at the top of your file.

Comment: Do `pod install` again and then check. Or try cleaning the project and build then run.

Comment: Thanks for the information.@TheTiger helps me solve the problem ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the project helps me!It seems like I didn't configure cocoapods in appcode,when I first ran the project.so,appcode didn‘t find the pods files.