# When I use AppCode, I cannot use third-party libraries through CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, appcode

## Premise

### AppCode version:

> AppCode 2019.3.5 Build #OC-193.6494.48, built on February 12, 2020

### Language

> Swift 5.0

### CocoaPods:

#### version

> CocoaPods 1.8.3

#### repo

```
cocoapods-
- Type: CDN
- URL:  https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
- Path: /Users/***/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods-

ModuleSpecs
- Type: git (master)
- URL:  https://git.private pod source.com/***.git
- Path: /Users/***/.cocoapods/repos/ModuleSpecs

Specs
- Type: git (master)
- URL:  https://git.private pod source.com/***.git
- Path: /Users/***/.cocoapods/repos/Specs
```

#### Public podfile

```rb
source 'https://git.private pod source.com/***.git'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

workspace 'IM.xcworkspace'

platform :ios, '10.0'

use_frameworks!

#use_modular_headers!
inhibit_all_warnings!

install! 'cocoapods',
         :preserve_pod_file_structure => true,
         :generate_multiple_pod_projects => true
#         :incremental_installation => true

target 'IM' do

  project 'IM/IM.xcodeproj'

  # pod some private component

  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'M13Checkbox'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'MJRefresh'

end

target 'Router' do

  project 'Router/Router.xcodeproj'

  # pod some private component

end
```

## Question:

When I run my project using AppCode and manage third-party libraries through CocoaPods, I cannot use the code in the third-party library in the **editor**. but **the project can run successfully**! ?

Take a piece of code from `Kingfisher` as an example:

```swift
import Kingfisher

...

imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL (string: ""))
```

1. I can't click `Kingfisher` with `cmd + left click` to preview Kingfisher's code
2. This code is not highlighted in AppCode
3. Nothing about `kf` in code hints, Means I need to manually write any method I need without any hint
4. When I use `cmd + left click` on the `setImage (with:)` method, AppCode prompts *Cannot find declaration to go to*

However, with the exception of the second point, **none of the above problems have occurred in my private pods**, that is, only the pods in the **CDN source (`cocoapods-`)** have the above problems.

This has had a big impact on my development ... How can I solve this problem?

## supplement:

I now suspect that there is a problem with the configuration of the CocoaPods in my AppCode.

Because a friend of mine's Preferences-> CocoaPods settings are shown below. The pod with the CDN source is included in the settings, and there are tips about the CDN source

[image]

But what I see below is that it only contains my private pods, no information about the shared pods, and no tips about the CDN

[image]

Comment: Maybe just you should clean the cache of your project. Please check these out -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/cleaning-system-cache.html : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173849/appcode-cannot-find-class-installed-by-cocoapods

Comment: @emrcftci I tried the above two methods, but they can't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I executed `Clean`,`Clean Build Folder`, `Invalidate Caches` numerous times, although the relevant code is still not highlighted, I can click to view the statement.

I do n’t know which operation fixed the problem, if you have this problem, you can try more operations